# spdiags and features scaling

Tags: matlab, scaling, libsvm

According to libsvm faqs, the following one-line code scale each feature to the range of [0,1] in Matlab

```
(data - repmat(min(data,[],1),size(data,1),1))*spdiags(1./(max(data,[],1)-min(data,[],1))',0,size(data,2),size(data,2))
```

so I'm using this code:

```
v_feature_trainN=(v_feature_train - repmat(mini,size(v_feature_train,1),1))*spdiags(1./(maxi-mini)',0,size(v_feature_train,2),size(v_feature_train,2));
 v_feature_testN=(v_feature_test - repmat(mini,size(v_feature_test,1),1))*spdiags(1./(maxi-mini)',0,size(v_feature_test,2),size(v_feature_test,2));
```

where I use the first one to train the classifier and the second one to classify...

In my humble opinion scaling should be performed by:

[image]

i.e.:

```
v_feature_trainN2=(v_feature_train -min(v_feature_train(:)))./(max(v_feature_train(:))-min((v_feature_train(:))));
v_feature_test_N2=(v_feature_test  -min(v_feature_train(:)))./(max(v_feature_train(:))-min((v_feature_train(:))));
```

Now I compared the classification results using these two scaling methods and the first one outperforms the second one.
The question are:
1) What exactly does the first method? I didn't understand it.
2) Why the code suggested by libsvm outperforms the second one (e.g. 80% vs 60%)?
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Could you be consistent with the variable names? Maybe use `data` for the second version too.

Comment: Protip: Instead of writing the exact same code twice with slightly different variable names you should define a function. You could even use an anonymous function like this. `normalize = @(D) (D-min(D(:)))./(max(D(:))-min(D(:)));` and then use: `v_feature_trainN = normalize(v_feature_train)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:
The code described in the `libsvm` does something different than your code:

It maps every column independently onto the interval `[0,1]`.
Your code however uses the global `min` and `max` to map all the columns using the same affine transformation instead of a separate transformation for each column.

---

The first code works in the following way:

- `(data - repmat(min(data,[],1),size(data,1),1))`
  This subtracts each column's minimum from the entire column. It does this by computing the row vector of minima `min(data,[],1)` which is then replicated to build a matrix the same size as `data`. Then it is subtracted from `data`.
- `spdiags(1./(max(data,[],1)-min(data,[],1))',0,size(data,2),size(data,2))`
  This generates a diagonal matrix. The entry `(i,i)` of this matrix is 1 divided by the difference of the maximum and the minimum of the `i`th column: `max(data(:,i))-min(data(:,i))`.
- The right multiplication of this diagonal matrix means: Multiply each column of the left matrix with the corresponding diagonal entry. This effectively divides column `i` by `max(data(:,i))-min(data(:,i))`.

---

Instead of using a sparse diagonal matrix, you could do this even more efficiently with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
bsxfun(@rdivide, ...
       bsxfun(@minus, ...
              data, min(data,[],1)), ...
       max(data,[],1)-min(data,[],1))
```

Which is the matlab way of writing:

- Divide:

  - The difference of:

    - each column and its respective minimum
  - by the difference of each column's `max` and `min`.

Comment: @Kevin: I have no idea what the algorithm you are using is based on, as you didn't mention it in any way. So scaling the entire matrix could make as much sense as scaling the individual columns.

Comment: scaling each column by their respective min and max value is the correct way to go since every feature (column) will span a different range of values. Let's say you have two columns: age and blood pressure. Age will span the range 18-80, but the blood pressure might be from 70 to 180. Also you have to consider that such values will be used for a dissimilarity measure in SVM (i.e. kernel function) and some metrics (such as Euclidean) will weight differently features in different ranges. That's why every column must be in range [0;1] (i.e. normalized with its min-max)

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered correctly, but I would like to present another solution that I think is also correct and I found more intuitive/shorther then the one presented by knedlsepp. I am new to matlab and as I was studying knedlsepp solution, I found it more intuitive to solve this problem with the following formula:

```
function [ output ] = feature_scaling( y)

output = (y - repmat(min(y),size(y,1),1)) * diag(1./(max(y) - min(y)));

end
```

I find it a bit easier to use diag this way instead of spdiags, but I believe it produces the same result for the purpose of this excercise.

Multiplying the first term by the second, effectively divides each member of the matrix (Y-min(Y)) by the scalar value 1/(max(y)-min(y)), achieving the desired result.

In case someone prefers a shorter version, maybe this can be of help.